# Different NDVI Values for Landcover classes for Sentinel-2 and Landsat-8

Tags: arcmap, ndvi, sentinel-2, landsat-8

I created a classified image of my study area using random tree classifier method as shown:-
[image]
Fig 1: Classified Image of Landsat-8

[image]
Fig: Classified Image of Sentinel-2

I now want to classify image based ON NDVI value based on these images as reference. I classify Landsat image setting NDVI value as shown.
[image]
Fig: NDVI map of Landsat-8

I also classified Sentinel-2 image using NDVI value using above 2 reference images as shown.
[image]
Fig: NDVI map of Sentinel-2

But, on classifying these images land cover classes the NDVI values for landcover classes for these figures (3) & (4) are different for Landsat-8 (fig 3) & Sentinel- 2 (fig 4). Is this because they are different satellite images i.e. Landsat-8 & Sentinel-2 and it's like that??

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply the gain and biases to your images ?
Are they radiometrically coherent (TOA, BOA ?)

To be sure to have aligned S2 and Landsat-8 images, check the [HLS](https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/) (Harmonized Landsat-Sentinel) images created by NASA. The drawback of those is that S2 images are downsampled to 30m.